# Remove duplicate rows in Pandas (possibly by group)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have dataset, df, with the following data:

```
starttime               endtime              ID  Diff  
1/10/2020 9:05:00 PM    1/10/2020 9:05:10    A    10
1/10/2020 9:05:00 PM    1/10/2020 9:05:10    A    10
1/10/2020 9:06:00 PM    1/10/2020 9:06:10    B    10
```

Desired outcome:

```
starttime               endtime              ID Diff
1/10/2020 9:05:00 PM    1/10/2020 9:05:10    A  10
1/10/2020 9:06:00 PM    1/10/2020 9:06:10    B  10
```

If you notice, one of the rows from Group A was removed, because it was an exact duplicate:

```
1/10/2020 9:05:00 pm    1/10/2020 9:05:10    A   10
```

This is the code I am using, however, I am unsure as to what to include in the parentheses, or if this is correct:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep=False)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: just `df.drop_duplicates()` works fine , when you do a `keep=False` it deleted all duplicates , however `drop_duplicates()` by default keeps the first occurance of the duplicate by the docs:  `keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
False : Drop all duplicates.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply the column

`df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the docs. If you can't figure out what's most appropriate for your case, then ask again, providing a context (e.g. example).

The link is for pandas 0.25

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html